# If $R$ is Noetherian and $I$ an ideal why ideals in $R/I$ correspond to ideals in $R$ containing $I$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $R$ is Noetherian and $I$ an ideal why ideals in $R/I$ correspond  to ideals in $R$ containing $I$?

I read that if $J\supseteq I$ is an ideal of $R$ then each coset of $I$
is either contained in $J$ or disjoint from $J$
, and thus $J$
maps directly to a subset of R/I via the canonical projection homomorphism but i dont understand at all the part that says then each coset of $I$
is either contained in $J$ or disjoint from $J$ can you help me to understand that? thank you

Comment: In fact it has nothing to do with $R$ being Noetherian.